# Google Map V21, how to programatically stop the automatic location updates?

Tags: android, google-maps

Hello I am using a support map fragment for my Android map. Other than using default settings (no customisation), i noticed out of the box that the map seems to provide location updates automatically i.e. a dot on the map which tells where the user is and periodically updates.

My map fragment is apart of a layout whereby the map fragment visibility can be set to GONE and some other content is shown in its place.

My question is, how do i programmatically stop these location updates? I noticed when the activity which hosts the map fragment goes in a stop state, the location updates stop.

This is the behaviour i want to mimic but for when the visibility of the fragment changes.

In XML

```
<fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

Initialised in code

```
 SupportMapFragment mapFragment = ((SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map));
 mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
```

Some settings set in onMapReady callback

```
 mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        mGoogleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);
        mGoogleMap.setOnMyLocationButtonClickListener(this);
        mGoogleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);
```

Comment: try this    mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(false);

Comment: Are you sure Google Maps v21 updates the location automatically? Doesn't it have to make use of some Location API for that (i.e. Location Services, Fused Location)? If it has, you can stop the updates by unregistering the callbacks for the location service.

Comment: @RishadAppat Thanks that stopped the updates.

Comment: please accpt my answr...

Comment: @Piovezan Yes its strange, because i thought i would need to set this up myself but it appears that setMyLocationEnabled does this for you without any kind of setup. I cannot view source code of the Google map class so i cant check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(false);
```